# Identifying start and stop times for each unique case

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a sample data that looks like this:

| ID | Date | Stages |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | Red |
| 1 | 2020-01-02 | Yellow |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | Yellow |
| 1 | 2020-01-03 | Green |
| 1 | 2020-01-04 | Green |
| 1 | 2020-01-05 | Red |
| 2 | 2020-01-02 | Red |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | Red |
| 2 | 2020-01-03 | Yellow |
| 2 | 2020-01-04 | Red |
| 2 | 2020-01-05 | Yellow |
| 2 | 2020-01-06 | Yellow |

I want to find a dplyr based (or any other method?) solution in R so that I can identify the beginning and ending dates of each continuous stage for each ID. The variable **Stages** can repeat. The final output should look something like this:

| ID | Stages | Start Date | End Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Red | 2020-01-01 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | Yellow | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-03 |
| 1 | Green | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-04 |
| 1 | Red | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-05 |
| 2 | Red | 2020-01-02 | 2020-01-03 |
| 2 | Yellow | 2020-01-03 | 2020-01-03 |
| 2 | Red | 2020-01-04 | 2020-01-04 |
| 2 | Yellow | 2020-01-05 | 2020-01-06 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `data.table::rleid/dplyr::consecutive_id` to create a grouping column before we summarise or `reframe`

```
library(dplyr) # version >= 1.1.0
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID, grp = consecutive_id(Stages)) %>% 
  reframe(Stages = first(Stages), StartDate = first(Date),
    EndDate = last(Date)) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 × 4
     ID Stages StartDate  EndDate   
  <int> <chr>  <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 Red    2020-01-01 2020-01-01
2     1 Yellow 2020-01-02 2020-01-03
3     1 Green  2020-01-03 2020-01-04
4     1 Red    2020-01-05 2020-01-05
5     2 Red    2020-01-02 2020-01-03
6     2 Yellow 2020-01-03 2020-01-03
7     2 Red    2020-01-04 2020-01-04
8     2 Yellow 2020-01-05 2020-01-06
```

---

If we are using an older version of `dplyr`, use

```
library(data.table)
df1 %>%
   group_by(ID, grp = rleid(Stages)) %>%
   summarise(Stages = first(Stages), StartDate = first(Date),
    EndDate = last(Date)) %>%
  select(-grp)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L), Date = c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", 
"2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-02", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-03", 
"2020-01-04", "2020-01-05", "2020-01-06"), Stages = c("Red", 
"Yellow", "Yellow", "Green", "Green", "Red", "Red", "Red", "Yellow", 
"Red", "Yellow", "Yellow")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Tried this but I am unable to find functions consecutive_id or reframe in dplyr.

Comment: @PrathameshMohite your `packageVersion('dplyr') can be older.  You may either update the package or use the second solution I updated for older dplyr versions